# The format of a unit using DeclareSIUnit is being modified by \cdot

Tags: siunitx

I'd like to insert a cdot symbol at the beginning of the new variable \kPaf, so I don't need to write it all the time. When I try it, like in \cdotkPaf, the \dfrac is turned off. How to add \cdot in the beginning so it looks like the third equation, which uses only Math Mode?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\dfrac" macro
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction,fraction-function=\dfrac]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\kPaf}{\kilo\newton\per\meter\squared} 
\DeclareSIUnit{\cdotkPaf}{\cdot\kilo\newton\per\meter\squared}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
A=2\si{\kPaf} \\
A=2\si{\cdotkPaf} \\
A=2\cdot\dfrac{kN}{m^{2}}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}`?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `\cdot` to denote the (abstract) product of a scalar quantity (here: `2`) and the associated units (here: `\kPaf`), right? If so, it looks like you're abusing the `siunitx` machinery by trying to make the `\cdot` symbol a part of the units expression. Instead of writing

```
A=2\si{\cdotkPaf}
```

you really should be writing

```
A=\SI[number-unit-product=\cdot]{2}{\kPaf}
```

Observe that `\SI` takes two mandatory arguments: a number part and a units part. Naturally, the option `number-unit-product=\cdot` may be stated when running `\sisetup`; that way, it doesn't have to be restated each time one uses `\SI`.

Incidentally, do reconsider if you even need `\cdot`. A thinspace (the default when using `SI`) is every bit as effective at separating the numbers and units.

Separately, I don't think it's a great idea to provide the option `fraction-function=\dfrac`. Even without this option, display-style fraction notation will be used automatically if TeX is in display-style math mode. Without this option, though, the more reasonable `\tfrac` would be used in inline math mode. By using `\dfrac` in inline math mode, one pretty much assures the creation of a complete typographic train wreck. For inline math applications of `\SI` and `\si`, do consider using the option `per-mode=symbol` for an "un-cramped" look.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[per-mode=fraction, % default is "per-mode=symbol"
            number-unit-product=\cdot % <-- new
           ]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\kPaf}{\kilo\newton\per\meter\squared} 

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
A=2\cdot\si{\kPaf}  \quad
A=\SI{2}{\kPaf}     \quad
A=\SI[number-unit-product=\,]{2}{\kPaf} $

\bigskip
\sisetup{number-unit-product={\,}} % revert to default
$A=\SI{2}{\kPaf} \quad
 A=\SI[per-mode=symbol]{2}{\kPaf}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I was setting \dfrac only to check the behavior of \cdot inside the function I was willing to create. Now I get including the \cdot was away too much. Thank you for the clarification!